# Darken background but not inside contents - React / Ionic /CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, filter, background, background-color

I need to darken the background of an image but not its contents inside like the below picture. The image is being painted programatically so I cannot have its url in the css.

Below how it should look like:

[image: This is how it should look like]

And now how it´s looking for me, I need the characters much whiter:

[image]

I´ve looked at different answers using ::before or ::after but given my image is being rendered inline it does not work. Below my code.

REACT.TSX

```
 {apartments.map(({ name, images, taskStatus }: any, index: number) => (
            <Link key={index} to={`/apartments/${index}`}>
              <div
                className="apartmentImage"
                style={{
                  backgroundImage: `url(${API_IMAGE}${images[0]})`,
                }}
              >
                <div
                  className="center ion-margin-top"
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                >
                  <h5 className="apartmentText">{name}</h5>
                </div>
                <div
                  className="center ion-margin-top"
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                >
                  <h6 className="subApartmentText">MALAGA</h6>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Link>
          ))}
```

CSS:

```
.apartmentImage {
  width: 98%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  height: 24.7vh;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: -1%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: brightness(0.8);
}

.apartmentText {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Any idea on what to do?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
{apartments.map(({ name, images, taskStatus }: any, index: number) => (
            <Link key={index} to={`/apartments/${index}`}>
              <div
                className="apartmentImage"
                style={{
                  backgroundImage: `url(${API_IMAGE}${images[0]})`,
                }}
              >
                <div
                  className="center ion-margin-top"
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                >
                  <h5 className="apartmentText">{name}</h5>
                </div>
                <div
                  className="center ion-margin-top"
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                >
                  <h6 className="subApartmentText">MALAGA</h6>
                <div className='color-overlay'/>

                </div>
              </div>
            </Link>
          ))}
```

And CSS:

```
.apartmentImage {
  width: 98%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  height: 24.7vh;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: -1%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;

}

.apartmentText {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}


.apartmentText, .subApartmentText {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.color-overlay{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

I tried it and it worked for me, but locally I made some changes, so I can load an image. Please let me know if something is not working, so I can double check if I copied all the code correctly.

Comment: You are a super star @Enchew!! You solved my problem!

To whoever has this problem of trying to darken background but not inside elements follow this advise.

Comment: You are very welcome my friend! I am glad I helped! Please mark the answer as accepted, so others know that this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this with css?

```
background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) ),
```